# How to classify the text which are not belong to the classes which I have to "Unknown" in text classifcation?

Tags: nlp, text-classification

I am working on a NLP problem to classify the text to four classes. 
1. Sports
2. Entertainment
3. Astrology
4. Unknown

I have created a training dataset for Sports, Entertainment, Astrology. But How to create a training dataset for "Unknown" category or how to classify the text which are not belong to first three category to the last category i.e "Unknown category"

Answer (score 0):

I would select documents/texts which do not belong to any of the first 3 class.

There is an important catch here, probably that number of documents is going to be very high in comparison to the number of documents in each other class, so probably what you want to do is to sub-sample (for instances, randomly choosing a number of documents) that `Unknown` class.